# VSM/ESM shadow mapping

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I have been trying to implement some shadow mapping using the VSM and ESM techniques in WebGL, but there is a few things causing me problems.

Since both methods are based around `occluder – receiver` depth value, the bigger the difference between the obstacle and the point we want to lit, the lesser light it is going to receive.

So from what I understand, an object 10units away from the ground is going to cast a weaker shadow than an object 1000units away?

Am I misunderstanding something? Here is a picture of my result using ESM, the problem is that there is almost no shadow at the base of the object.

[image]

#### Here is the ESM code used:

```c
float c = 4.0;
vec4 texel = texture2D(uDepthMap, depth.xy);
shadow = clamp(exp(-c * (depth.z - unpack(texel))), 0.0, 1.0);

gl_FragColor = vec4(color*shadow, 1.0);
```

For information, I took most of the code from http://devmaster.net/posts/3002/shader-effects-shadow-mapping

Comment: Hm, looks like it should be exactly opposite; the *lesser* the distance, the more pronounced the shadow. Altough [this image](http://devmaster.net/assets/post/3002/uploads/images/PointESM1.png) looks like what you have.

Comment: well yes, i would also think it should be the opposite, but every example I saw is doing something close to that.

Comment: @user1278743, did you find the solution to the problem? I have same issue

Comment: @Zheden I don't fully remember, but I don't think there is an easy solution, this is how the method is supposed to work. With VSM, if you play a bit with the constants it will be (a lot) less visible (probably depends on other factors like the type of objects you have and the precision you use for your shadow map). Once you manage to make the non-shadowed area touch your object you can use the lack of light behind the object to "hide" the missing shadow.

Comment: @user1278743 thanks a lot the comment!